# The content type 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' is not supported in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, http, post, web

So I'm just trying to make a simple post request using httpclient in RoR.

I'm going through a proxy, doing ntlm authentication with the server ( I can make GET requests without a problem).

Now when I try and do a post request, I get the error mentioned in the title...

`proxy = ENV['HTTP_PROXY']
     client=HTTPClient.new(proxy)
     client.set_auth(nil,user,pass)
     body= [{'Content-Type' => 'application/atom+xml, :content => ...}]
     res = client.post('url',body)
     puts res.body`

How am i getting this error when I clearly specify the header as atom+xml..?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use

```
res = client.post('url', 
          :body => "...body content...", 
          :header => {'Content-Type' => 'application/atom+xml'})
```

Comment: you're a god among men

Comment: It was nothing,  go and get a double-double :-)